# Changing 1 value of an arrays makes the other values null

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I have multiple edit text in a recycler view which is placed inside another recycler view. When I change the text of that recycler view, I send the interface event to the parent recycler view. This is how the interface callback looks:

```kotlin
override fun onOptionTextChanged(position: Int, text: String) {
   val oldOptions = questions[holder.adapterPosition].options.copyOf()
   Log.d(TAG, "onOptionTextChanged: oldOptions: ${oldOptions.contentToString()}")
   questions[holder.adapterPosition].options = arrayOfNulls(questionOptionAddList.size)
   for (oldDataIndex in oldOptions.indices){
      questions[holder.adapterPosition].options[oldDataIndex]?.text = oldOptions[oldDataIndex]!!.text
   }
   questions[holder.adapterPosition].options[position] = QuestionOptionAdd(text = text)
   Log.d(TAG, "onOptionTextChanged: newOptions: ${questions[holder.adapterPosition].options.contentToString()}")
}
```

But I get a weird issue. Whenever I change the value of 1 edit text, the other values go to null. So, I tried checking the old and new arrays which I created and then got this in my log:

```
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: oldOptions: []
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: newOptions: [QuestionOptionAdd(text=n, hasImage=false, imageUrl=), null]
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: oldOptions: [QuestionOptionAdd(text=n, hasImage=false, imageUrl=), null]
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: newOptions: [QuestionOptionAdd(text=no, hasImage=false, imageUrl=), null]

// from here, I started to write in the other edit text

D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: oldOptions: [QuestionOptionAdd(text=no, hasImage=false, imageUrl=), null]
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: newOptions: [null, QuestionOptionAdd(text=y, hasImage=false, imageUrl=)]
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: oldOptions: [null, QuestionOptionAdd(text=y, hasImage=false, imageUrl=)]
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: newOptions: [null, QuestionOptionAdd(text=ye, hasImage=false, imageUrl=)]
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: oldOptions: [null, QuestionOptionAdd(text=ye, hasImage=false, imageUrl=)]
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: newOptions: [null, QuestionOptionAdd(text=yes, hasImage=false, imageUrl=)]

// from here, I started to write in the other edit text

D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: oldOptions: [null, QuestionOptionAdd(text=yes, hasImage=false, imageUrl=)]
D/AddFormQuestionsAdapter: onOptionTextChanged: newOptions: [QuestionOptionAdd(text=no , hasImage=false, imageUrl=), null]
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: you literally put them to `null` with `arrayOfNulls`

Comment: Yes, @IvoBeckers, because I wanted to create the array again with a different size. So, I had to make it null, add the old values again, and then pass the new value again. Am I clear? Also, you can look out for my long comment on the answer below.

Comment: I understand the answer, but I believe you don't. The problem is that you are not adding the old values again. you are just trying to set the text on them, but they are `null`. They need to be `QuestionOptionAdd` objects

Comment: oh. u r right. I just missed that out. i will check and let u know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
questions[holder.adapterPosition].options[oldDataIndex]?.text = oldOptions[oldDataIndex]!!.text
```

this doesn't do anything because you try to set the text on something that is null.

I believe maybe you want this:

```
questions[holder.adapterPosition].options[oldDataIndex] = oldOptions[oldDataIndex]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're doing this

```
// I'm pulling this out so it's not constantly repeated, it's just easier to read!
val question = questions[holder.adapterPosition]

// wipe all the options to null
question.options = arrayOfNulls(questionOptionAddList.size)
// iterate over all the old options you copied
for (oldDataIndex in oldOptions.indices){
    // copy the text to the option in the same position, unless it's null -
    // they're all null though, you just set it to a null array, so this does nothing!
    question.options[oldDataIndex]?.text = oldOptions[oldDataIndex]!!.text
}
// create a new item at the position you're editing - so you end up with one item
// in an array of nulls
question.options[position] = QuestionOptionAdd(text = text)
```

So you're basically clearing everything to null, trying to copy your text back to your null objects (which you can't, they're gone) and then adding one new item back in.

Honestly I'm not sure why you're doing this? Why do you need to copy the original data, wipe it, then copy it back again? Can't you just do something like this?

```
override fun onOptionTextChanged(position: Int, text: String) {
    // grab the current data, or create (and add) a new one if it's null
    val options = questions[holder.adapterPosition].options
    val questionOption = options[position]
        ?: QuestionOptionAdd().also { options[position] = it }
    // set the text on the object
    questionOption.text = text
}
```

Comment: what is that `option.text = text`? from where did u get that? Also, what is the use of `questionOption`? It is unused

Comment: And, I guess you understood my code wrong. Before changing the array to null, I am copying that array to another variable.

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal Sorry, I renamed `option` to `questionOption` so it doesn't get confused with `options`, guess I missed one! And I know you're copying the array - like I said, you're trying to use that copy to set the `text` values on the original, *but there's nothing to set them on*. `question.options[oldDataIndex]` always evaluates to *null* because every item in `options` is null now, so `question.options[oldDataIndex]?.text = oldOptions[oldDataIndex]!!.text` does nothing. So you end up with an array of nulls, before you create a new `QuestionOptionAdd` on the `position` you're editing

Comment: I guess I am not clear, and you cannot reach the point because of that. So, I will explain it more now. First of all, I have a recycler view which has another recycler view. [This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx6C2.png). So, I have that `x` option in front of every option. And those options are placed inside another recycler view. Now, I can remove those options using that `x` mark. So, the size of that options array changes. That is why I used that method.

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal I'm just telling you what the code you posted is doing. You copy your array, clear the original, attempt (and always fail) to copy your `text` parameters back, your array is still full of nulls. That's why they're "all going to null" which is what you were asking about. Here, look: https://pl.kotl.in/sV66MwM_y

Comment: Thanks, @cactustictacs it does my task.